# Ethereum Node on Azure Virtual Machine (windows) remote access

Tags: go-ethereum, microsoft-azure, firewalls, azure

I've a Windows Server VM on Azure where geth is running quite good (no mining, just node).

Now, the "start command" is:

```
geth --rpcapi "eth,web3,db,net,personal,admin" --rpcaddr "10.0.0.4" --port "30303" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcport "8545" --rpc --ws --wsaddr "10.0.0.4" --nat "any"
```

From the Virtual Machine itself, I can go on the browser and write

```
 http://10.0.0.4:8545
```

And everything is working. 
From "outside" I try to access to

```
http://virtualmachineip:8545
```

And I get a Timeout, event if the firewall rule I configured is TOTALLY permissive like:

[image]

What could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: try with --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0"

Comment: @kherwa most probably it will not work for Windows, it would be better to skip setting `rpcaddr` (default `localhost`) or set to `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 2):

Go to the loadbalancer --> Inbound NAT Rules and add a New rule pointing to your VM and teh port as 8545

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that it was not enough to "open the port" from the Web Interface.
After I opened also on Windows everything worked smoothly!